# Excel Vlookup, creating key pair with a pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a key in a spreadsheet , `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A14,Stack_Pivot!A:D,4,FALSE),"0")`

A14 is `='Sheet1'!C2&"stack"&" Total"` , which is `43383stack Total`. Sheet1 C2 is a date.

So in my pivot I have,

```
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| Row Labels |    node    | productType2 |  Sum of sum  |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|      43383 |            | superuser    |            0 |
|      43383 | stackTotal | overflow     | -21541.23726 |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

How can I get my vlookup to retrieve the correct data?

Comment: In your pivot table, perhaps just create a helper column of `='Sheet1'!C2&'Sheet1!D2` and use that?

Comment: i guess, i wanted to do it without touching the sheet, or have it done within the formula or pivot table.

Comment: Why not just do `...VLOOKUP('Sheet1'!C2&"stack", ...` and skip the middleman cell `A14`?

Comment: but doesnt my pivot need to have `43383stack Total` . I think the sheet im doing the vlookup in is fine, its matching it on the pivot.

Comment: Almost like i Need to combine `43383stack Total` in the pivot or in the lookup part of the vlookup formula.

Comment: Exactly. Or you could replace `A14` in the Vlookup formula with `TRIM(LEFT(A14,SEARCH(" ",A14)-1))` ..but would still need to combine the two columns in the table.  Edit: Wait, can you change `A14`'s formula to `='Sheet1'!C2&"stack"&"Total"`, then replace `A14` in the vlookup with my suggestion? That should work.

Comment: okay so my new lookup formula, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(LEFT(A14,SEARCH(" ",A14)-1)),stackt_Pivot!A:D,4,FALSE),"0")` and in a14 I got , `='Sheet1'!C2&"Stack"&" Total"` .  Not returning anything where the vlookup should return..  Am I doing this correctly?